# Struct.Error, Must Be a Bytes Object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to execute the code:

```
    values = (1, 'ab', 2.7)    
    s.struct.Struct('I 2s f')
    packed = s.pack(*values)
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object
```

Why? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 25):

With Python 3, `'ab'` isn't a `bytes` object, what was called a `str` on Python 2, it's `unicode`. You need to use:

```
values = (1, b'ab', 2.7)
```

which tells Python that `'ab'` is a byte literal. See [PEP 3112](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/) for more info.