# struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object in python 3.4

Tags: python, networking

Code I'm attempting to use in python 3.4:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
 def get_mac_addr(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    info = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8927,  struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15]))
    return ''.join(['%02x:' % ord(char) for char in info[18:24]])[:-1]
 print (get_mac_addr('eth0'))

Error: struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object
```

I see that this code does work when not using python3 but I need it in 3 for my project. I tried comparing to problem: [Struct.Error, Must Be a Bytes Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082623/struct-error-must-be-a-bytes-object) but I couldn't see how I can apply this to myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert the `ifname` string into bytes. You also don't need to call ord(), since ioctl returns bytes, not a string:

```
...
info = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8927,  struct.pack('256s', bytes(ifname[:15], 'utf-8')))
return ''.join(['%02x:' % b for b in info[18:24]])[:-1]
...
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3) for more info about strings and bytes in python3

Comment: Thanks! I think this(or something else?) may be causing another error. "TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found" I believe ord() is supposed to return an integer representing the Unicode code point of the string entered... anything you can direct me towards in this code specifically?

Comment: Works perfectly! Been struggling with this for hours, thank you! I couldn't quite figure out the logic behind it.